# Searching for text in a file

Tags: python, file, search

hi there got a couple of probs, say in my text file i have:

- abase
- abased
- abasement
- abasements
- abases

This coding below is meant to find a word in a file and print all the lines to the end of the file. But it doesnt it only prints out my search term and not the rest of the file.

```
search_term = r'\b%s\b' % search_term

for line in open(f, 'r'):
    if re.match(search_term, line):
        if search_term in line:
            f = 1
        if f: print line,
```

Say i searched for abasement, i would like the output to be:

> abasement
>
> abasements
>
> abases

---

My final problem is, i would like to search a file a print the lines my search term is in and a number of lines befer and after the searchterm. If i searched the text example above with 'abasement' and i defined the number of lines to print either side as 1 my output would be:

> abased
>
> abasement
>
> abasements

```
numb = ' the number of lines to print either side of the search line '
search_term = 'what i search'
f=open("file")
d={}
for n,line in enumerate(f):
    d[n%numb]=line.rstrip()
    if search_term in line:
        for i in range(n+1,n+1+numb):
            print d[i%numb]
        for i in range(1,numb):
            print f.next().rstrip()
```

Comment: @harpalss, if you don't find you're getting enough help, you might want to go back and actually accept (click on checkmark next to best one) some of the answers you've already got on your other questions.  Maybe vote a few "helpful" ones up too.  That gets you and the answers reputation points, which helps people know you're serious and paying attention.  It also helps other people, who may search with similar questions, to find the best answers more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the question, unindent your `if f: print line,`. Otherwise, you're only trying to print when the regex matches.

It's not clear to me what your question is in the second part. I see what you're trying to do, and your code, but you've not indicated how it misbehaves.

Comment: i get a Typeerror: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'
which occurs at: d[n%numb] = line.rstrip()

Comment: you get a type error because numb is a string.  try setting numb to an actual number and put the description as a comment

Answer (score 1):

For the first part the algorithm goes like this (in pseudo code):

```
found = False
for every line in the file:
    if line contains search term:
        found = True
    if found:
        print line
```

Comment: If he wants to print every line after the match, wouldn't it be better to stop checking once a match is found and then print every line after it?

Comment: @danben: yes. That first 'if' could be rewritten as "if not found and line contains the search term"